# When using a custom decorator function for logging, how should the arguments be passed?

Tags: python, logging, decorator, python-decorators, python-logging

**Question:** Is the approach of passing the logger object to the decorator function a good idea for logging?

**Background:**
My goal is to implement logging in combination with a decorator function, according to aspect oriented programming.

Now I thought of the following possibillites:

**A.** I could pass the `logger` object (getting it from `logging.getLogger(__name__)`) to the decorator function
like this: `@Log(logger)`

**B.** I could pass arguments to decorator and instanciate the logger within the decorator function

```
def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _log(*args, **kwargs):
          logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # <-- like this
          logger.info("...")
          # ...
```

But I neglected this approach because I thought `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` would be not a good idea, because the file would be opened everytime logging is made. Therefore I chose the first (A) approach, where I pass the logger instance directly to the decorator function.

**Following the first (A) appraoch, I created the following decorator function:**

```
class Log:   # <-- defining it here

    def __init__(self, logger: Logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _log(*args, **kwargs):
            self.logger.debug(f"executing: {func.__module__}.{func.__name__} with arguments: {args} {kwargs}")
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            self.logger.debug(f"executed: {func.__module__}.{func.__name__}
            return result
result arguments: {result}")
        return _log
```

and now Iam using it like this:

```
import logging

from app.logger import Log

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@Log(logger) 
def send_email():
    return None
```

***It is functioning, but is this good code ? or are there better ways to accomplish it ?***